# When are the Schoen-Yau minimal surfaces embedded?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, geometric-analysis, minimal-surfaces

In 1979, Rick Schoen and Shing-Tung Yau published an Annals paper in which they proved the existence of so-called 'incompressible' minimal surfaces in compact Riemannian manifolds.

**Question.** Under what conditions is such an incompressible minimal surface $\Sigma^2 \to N^3$ known to be *embedded*?

The first thing that would come to my mind would be a topological condition, or something with the curvature of $N$, but I'd be interested in abstract answers too. (E.g. 'If you want to prove that such a $\Sigma \subset N$ is embedded, the first thing to try is ...')

If the homology class $[f(\Sigma)] \in H_2(N)$ of the image of $f: \Sigma \to M$ were non-zero, then one could resolve the immersed singularities and minimize area among all surfaces in the same class. But then $H_2(N) \neq 0$, which—it seems to me—kind of defeats the purpose of following the Schoen–Yau approach in the first place...

*Background.*
I'll give some more background information, which those familiar with the paper need not read.

My foremost interest lies with the three-dimensional case; the setting was the following. Let $N^3$ be a closed, orientable Riemannian manifold.  If $\pi_1(N)$ is known to contain a subgroup $G$ abstractly isomorphic to the fundamental group of a Riemann surface $\Sigma_g$ with genus $g \geq 1$, then there exists a minimal *immersion* $f: \Sigma_g \to N$ with $f_\# (\pi_1(\Sigma_g)) = G$. (The results are actually more general, but I'll restrict to this simpler setting.) Moreover, $f(\Sigma_g)$ has the least area among all maps homotopic to it.

The map $f$ is constructed in two steps, first as a harmonic map by minimizing the Dirichlet energy, which is then made conformal—and thus a *branched* minimal immersion—by varying the conformal structure. The construction works in arbitrary dimensions, but when $\operatorname{dim} N = 3$ there are no branch points.

Comment: Are you familiar with the paper "Least Area Incompressible Surfaces in 3-Manifolds" by Freedman, Hass and Scott?  It shows the surface is embedded if there is a a two sided embedding in the homotopy class (modulo some technical issues).

Comment: @RBega2 Nice, this looks like a very cool paper, thank you! Can I ask you a follow-up? For examples of one-sided minimal surfaces, I've only got $\mathbf{R}P^2 \subset \mathbf{R}P^3$... (If my memory is correct, that is.) In the paper they also mention examples based on Moebius bands and Klein bottles. Are there any other examples you'd recommend? Just to get a better grasp of 'what's going on'.